SwiftUI ternary-set theme doesn't update until view is reopened
I have custom color schemes for my app, but I also use a few basic built-in views. One example is I have a sheet to control the app's settings. The theme of the app is changed with a Picker, and then the .preferredColorScheme is updated based on which theme was selected: .preferredColorScheme(theme.foregroundColor == .dark ? .light : .dark).
However, the color of the sheet doesn't change until it is closed and re-opened. Is there any way to force the sheet's color theme to update?
Example:
@Binding var theme: Theme
/* ... */
.sheet(isPresented: true) {
    NavigationStack {
        Form {
            Picker("Theme", selection: $theme) {
                ForEach(Theme.allCases) { th in
                    Text(th.name).tag(th)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
        }
    }
}
.preferredColorScheme(theme.accentColor == .dark ? .light : .dark)


Can you include a [mre]?

To change the sheet theme as well, add another .preferredColorScheme(theme.accentColor == .dark ? .light : .dark) inside the sheet view, for example:
 .sheet(isPresented: true) {
     NavigationStack {
         Form {
             Picker("Theme", selection: $theme) {
                 ForEach(Theme.allCases) { th in
                     Text(th.name).tag(th)
                 }
             }
             .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
         }
     }
    .preferredColorScheme(theme.accentColor == .dark ? .light : .dark) // <-- here
 }
 .preferredColorScheme(theme.accentColor == .dark ? .light : .dark)

